# Python Requests, найти данные элемента

Tags: python, парсер, requests, bs4

пытаюсь через Requests и bs4  достать ключ csrf токена, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не получается получить значение элемента "data-csrf-token", прошу помощи как правильно его оттуда достать

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = requests.Session()
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0'}

link = "mysite"

xsfr_token_find = session.get(link,headers= header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(xsfr_token_find, 'lxml')
xsfr = soup.find('div', id= 'main_content')
sxsfr1 = xsfr.find('div', class_='react-root')
print (sxsfr1)
```

Удалось добраться до его блока, но дальше не понимаю как действовать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc.ru/bs4ru.html#id15